# How to wrap same classes inside one parent div using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have some div with 2 different classes like the one below

```
<div class = "leftAlign">One</div>
<div class = "leftAlign">Two</div>
<div class = "leftAlign">Three</div>
<div class = "leftAlign">Four</div>
<div class = "rightAlign">Five</div>
<div class = "rightAlign">Six</div>
<div class = "rightAlign">Seven</div>
```

and I want to wrap all the classes with leftAlign class inside a parent div, something like this

```
<div class = "wrapper">
   <div class = "leftAlign">One</div>
   <div class = "leftAlign">Two</div>
   <div class = "leftAlign">Three</div>
   <div class = "leftAlign">Four</div>
<div>
<div class = "rightAlign">Five</div>
<div class = "rightAlign">Six</div>
<div class = "rightAlign">Seven</div>
```

This is what I have done, but it does not seems to work

```
let target = document.querySelectorAll('leftAlign');
let wrapper = document.createElement('div');
wrapper.classList.add('wrapper');
target.parentNode.insertBefore(wrapper, target);
wrapper.appendChild(target);
```

Comment: If this is a react question then please include your react component code rendering the divs with classes.

Comment: *so maybe we have to append it dynamically* - we? How about you show how you have tried :p

Comment: Well, the already-provided answers *could* help you, but direct DOM manipulations are generally considered an anti-pattern in react. I see no reason why you couldn't figure out before rendering what class each element will have and place into the appropriate group for rendering and skip the issue of DOM synchronicity. ‍♂️

Answer (score 1):

here you go

```js
var lefties = document.querySelectorAll('.leftAlign');
var first = lefties[0];
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.classList.add('contain');
first.replaceWith(div);
lefties.forEach(d => div.appendChild(d));
```

```css
.rightAlign {
  text-align:right;
}
.leftAlign {
  text-align:left;
  background:red;
  
}
.contain>.leftAlign {
  background:transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="leftAlign">One</div>
<div class="leftAlign">Two</div>
<div class="leftAlign">Three</div>
<div class="leftAlign">Four</div>
<div class="rightAlign">Five</div>
<div class="rightAlign">Six</div>
<div class="rightAlign">Seven</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. create the parent element

```
    const container = document.createElement('div');
    container.setAttribute('class', 'wrapper');
```

2. get the child elements you want the above parent to encapsulate

```
    const children = document.querySelectorAll('.leftAlign');
```

3. loop through children and append to parent

```
    children.forEach(function(child) {
      container.appendChild(child);
    });
```

4. append container to the area in the dom you wish to place it (e.g. if body)

```
document.body.appendChild(container);
```

Comment: sure, but container isn't in the DOM yet - so, you've effectively removed the leftAlign's from the DOM

Comment: @JaromandaX ahh I missed that bit, edited answer. Thanks for the heads up

Comment: append to the end of the body? that'll change the order won't it

Comment: @JaromandaX I'm not aware of the OPs overall containing element so used `body` as an example

Comment: no need ... see my answer :p replace the first matching div with the container :p